# How to share Image and text on Facebook?

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the `ShareButton` in order to share a combination of an `Image` and a `String`.

On most targets (Gmail, Slack, Twitter...), the `ShareButton` do it's job and share the image and the text, as I need it.

But when targetting FB or Messenger, only the image is shared. 
Is it a way to force sharing the image AND the text to FB ? Or a way to detect that the sharing target don't support both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share is implemented natively by the applications on the device. We can't tell if an app chooses to ignore some of the data we pass to it.

Comment: Is there a way to prioritize text over image in this case ?

Comment: No. We just don't know what the application will do with the information we provide to it. We submit data to the native API and the user picks the app. It's the responsibility of the app to do as it sees fit with the data we provided. Sometimes these apps do the wrong thing